Having issues with a yaml file specifically for deployment, But receiving an error
This is the webapp.yaml file below:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
  labels: 
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: nanajanashia/k8s-demo-app:v1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: USER_NAME
          valueFrom: 
             secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
        - name: USER_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
        - name: DB_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo-config
              key: mongo-url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30100

I tried to kubectl my webapp.yaml file to deploy it so it could be accessed via the browser but got this error below via my terminal:
deployment.apps/webapp-deployment created
error: error validating "webapp.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.ports[0]): unknown field "nodeport" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Hello, can you try commenting the "nodePort", it is anyways optional and K8 control plane will assign random port within range for you (--service-node-port-range flag range). If you still require to add a "nodePort", can you check if change the port number to something other than 30100 works ? If the conditions are failed the K8 API may fail to transact.
